# generating random the same numbers in verilog issue

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to generate the random numbers in verilog in verilog.
But the Problem is when I re-run the simulation, that random value is fixed.
so previous simulation value and current simulation random value are the same.

```
reg [20:0] temp;

integer  seed;
reg [31:0] rand;

initial fork 

seed = $random;

for (i=0; i<10; i=i+1)begin

temp  = $random(seed) %10 ;
end

wait(verif_fcnt == 3) begin
temp  = $random(seed) %10 ;
task1(temp[0],temp[7:0]); 
end
wait(verif_fcnt == 3) begin
temp  = $random(seed) %10;
 task2(temp[0],temp[7:0]);
end
wait(verif_fcnt == 3) begin
temp  = $random(seed) %10;
task3(temp[0],temp[7:0]);
end

join
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reproduce a bug, you want to 'control' the randomness. So that is something you want most of the time.

The `$random` system call is constrained by `seed`. When a seed is give the random calls will give the same sequence.

I would advise you to keep the seed parameter and generate it by a `$random` call (without seed). Just be sure to print the `seed` variable used in case you stumble upon a bug.

Instead of:

```
seed = 0;
```

Use:

```
seed = $random;
$display("Seed used: %d",seed);
```

**EDIT**

Seed value can also be set in the simulation command-line.
In NCsim for example, it is the `-seed integer` option that sets it.

In this case, you can add in your simulation script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SEED=$RANDOM
echo "Seed used: $SEED"
ncsim ...various command line options... -seed $SEED
```

**EDIT 2**

Verilog actually behaves (by default) like constant a seed is given so you can reproduce bugs [(see here)](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45156).

To manually pass a seed in Verilog source, you will have to use `$srandom(seed)` to initialize the seed of the next random calls. Then you should use `$urandom` instead of `$random` [(see here)](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/system_task_function5.html)

To generate the inital `seed`, I would try to use `$urandom` before setting the seed.

```
integer seed; 
initial begin
 seed = $urandom();
 $srandom(seed);
end
//**
  ... tests with $urandom() calls
**//
```

IMHO, It will finally be simpler to use the command line option.

Comment: When I re-run, the seed value always the same

Comment: In your simulation command it is possible to define a seed e.g. in NCsim `-seed $NUMBER` command-line option. This seed will automatically constrain the random calls in you simulation.

Comment: Is there any options to handle in the verilog not tool?

Comment: If you want to handle it in verilog my first option should work. However if your tool sets the seed in the command line it will override what you have set in your RTL. So you have to at least remove the option from the command line.

Comment: sorry but if you once run the simulation then you can recolonization. the problem is that the value which from $random function does not change after re-run.

Comment: Because it is certainly constrained by a command-line option.
Can you post the command line you use to lauch the simulation?

Comment: this is my lauch script.    #!/bin/csh -f
rm -rf INCA_libs/
irun -64bit +access+rwc \
        -timescale 1ns/1ps \
        -log fun.log    \
        ./tb_test.v \
        -f ../verif/file_list.f \
        +libext+.v